# I had a car or I had had a car

Tags: usage

He said " I had a car "

when this is converted into a reported speech, which of these is correct?
a) He said he had a car, or
b) He said he had had a car.

Comment: Also, how is this different from [“had to” or “ had had to” in a reported speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/256666/9161)?

Answer (score 0):

In reported speech, when backshifting (which is common but not always mandatory) you would backshift the past tense "I had a car" to "he had had a car".

The ugliness is somewhat disguised by the contraction:

> He said that he'd had a car.

That is the grammar.  But you'd not normally use "I had a car":  "I owned a car" or "I hired a car" would be a lot better.

> He said that he'd hired a car for the week.